# Does Anybody successfully run git-svn on M1 CPU Mac?

Tags: git, macos, svn, git-svn, apple-m1

I've tried so many ways posted on Homebrew issues.Always fail to run git-svn

> ```
> Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
> SVN::Core module) (@INC contains:
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/share/perl5
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/darwin-2level
> /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0
> /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/darwin-2level
> /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0) at
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
> Compilation failed in require at
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 25. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32.
> Compilation failed in require at
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.
> ```

Git-SVN do not support M1 Mac?

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that M1 has anything to do with this problem.

`git-svn` is written in [Perl](https://www.perl.org), and the interpreter itself appears to be working OK. It did produce a backtrace; the error would be different had it major troubles to run at all (due to a special machine you're using or whatnot).

If you could *read carefully* the output, you could easily understand what's the problem.

Let's just do that together.

> Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC

This says `git-svn` (a [perl script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.30.1/git-svn.perl)) tries to import/include/require a *module* `SVN/Core.pm`. The file for that module could not be found.

> Can't locate SVN/Core.pm **in @INC**

Even without intimate Perl knowledge, you could guess that `@INC` is the "include path" variable. List of directories where Perl looks for imported modules.

Reading further.

> ```
> @INC contains:
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/share/perl5
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/darwin-2level
> /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0
> /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/darwin-2level
> /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0)
> ```

This is exactly the current setting for `@INC`. It shows you that exact list of directories. *Read it carefully*, don't skip over! We're expecting to see something git-svn-related there, right?

Problem 1: your Perl module path appears to contain some junk. There're 2 version of Perl intermixed in there (5.28 & 5.32.0) which can't be a good sign. Did you frantically install multiple versions never cleaning up?..

Let's read the traceback next:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 25. 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.30.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.
```

`git-svn` [includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.30.1/git-svn.perl#L21) `Git::SVN`. Obviously, the `Git/SVN.pm` is located correctly by Perl; which indicates that at least some of the @INC paths do contain git & the corresponding git-svn modules. The [homebrew package](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git) is what got picked up.

Next in the chain is [`Git::SVN::Utils`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.30.1/perl/Git/SVN/Utils.pm#L6) which imports `SVN::Core` on line 6 thus triggering the crash.

Notice there's no `SVN/Core.pm` file, neither in [Git-2.30.1 Homebrew bottle for Big Sure](https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/git-2.30.2.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz) (that's what you get from `brew install git` on your M1) — neither in Git source!

That's because it comes from a [separate library](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Alien-SVN/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Core.pm) (`SVN::Core`, not `Git::SVN::Core`).

Problem 2: `git-svn` needs to have the `libsvn-perl` library installed, it's a dependency.

Can you `find / -path '*/SVN/Core.pm'` ? Is the dependency installed somewhere Perl is not looking?

Problem 3: the `git` [Homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/git.rb) should either declare the dependency onto `libsvn-perl` (which somebody should first create & upload as I'm not finding it packaged), or ship the dependency together with git, e.g. in the `/git/2.30.2/share/perl5/FromCPAN/` subdir of the "bottle"... because it's not there.

I won't go much further. What happened according to my hunch, is that nobody cared. SVN as such is *past century technology* (think about it); the [test section](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/git.rb#L159-L177) of the Git formula does check that sending emails works, but ignores git-svn.

You're welcome to contribute to the community effort which is Open Source. Fix the bug yourself if you care.

This has nothing to do with your hardware.

Comment: Wow! thanks for you did, I will continue to figure it out.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, posted on Homebrew issues #52490 page: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/52490#issuecomment-793464504